# MongoDb - Remove duplicates matching two criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called businesses. The business model looks thus:

```js
name: {
  type: String,
},
email: {
  type: String,
},
views: {
  type: Number
}
location: {
  lat: Number,
  lon: Number,
}
```

Some businesses have the same name but they are in different locations, I am okay with that. Some of them are however having the same name and still having the same location (location.lat and location.long), this category of businesses are the ones I will like to remove the duplicates from. Most solutions that I have seen deals with only one field match, how do I handle duplicates with two fields match please and I will like to sum the views of the matches

```js
const businesses = await Business.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    name: {
                        $ne: true,
                    },
                    location: {
                        $ne: true,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: { name: "$name" }, // can be grouped on multiple properties
                    dups: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
                    count: { $sum: 1 },
                },
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    count: { $gt: 1 }, // Duplicates considered as count greater than one
                },
            },
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not considering `location` in your `$group` statement.

```
const businesses = await Business.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    name: {
                        $ne: true,
                    },
                    location: {
                        $ne: true,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: { 
                      name: "$name",
                      location: "$location",  // <-- Add location too to be considered in the group
                    },
                    dups: { $push: "$_id" },  // <-- Changed from `$addToSet` to push since `_id` is alreadr unique and `$push` is faster than `$addToSet`
                    count: { $sum: 1 },
                },
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    count: { $gt: 1 },
                },
            },
        ]);
```